# How to call a node.js function from an express rendered ejs webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, webserver, express

I have an express server that has a button that issues a POST which activates a function in my node.js server.

Instead of sending a post, I would like to do something kind of like AJAX because I don't want a new page to load. If I use a Javascript button, is there a way I can directly call a function defined in the node.js server instead of having to send a post?

I noticed that JSON values can be passed into the .ejs webpage when it's rendered, but I haven't been able to get it to work for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Socket.io to emit an event from the browser, and than listen for that event on the server to act on it.

Socket.io works flawlessly with express http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/).  It lets you very easily invoke functions on the server from the client and vice-versa:

From the site:

> - NowJS creates a magic namespace "now", accessible by server and client
> - Functions and variables added to now are automatically synced, in real-time
> - Call client functions from the server and server functions from client